# IIS ReWrite rule based on word in url

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config

I am trying to create some rewrite rules (IIS7 ReWrite Module) for drive-by attempts to hack the website.

My problem is that I like to keep my 404 stat clean, but currently it is filled with URL's containing "wp-admin", "fckeditor" and software like that.

I would like to make a ReWrite if the URL contains some specific words somewhere in the URL. So far I made this one that works fine. It look for the word "wp-admin" somewhere in the URL and just rewrites to the homepage.

```
<rule name="Handle Hacks" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*wp-admin.*" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" />
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
</rule>
```

This solution requires a seperate rule for each word. Is there a way to create just one rule that can do the trick with "wp-admin", "fckeditor", "administrator" ect.?

Thanks

Comment: I have redirected these hackers to a free software download exe link so I guess whenever they bombard the server,  they should be getting a lot of downloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OR (symbol `|`) in your regexp like that:

```
<rule name="Handle Hacks" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(wp-admin|fckeditor|administrator)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
</rule>
```